# Make an outlook rule based off of all emails within a folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003, email-filter

I have a folder full of different emails. I would like to write a rule that will match any new email like the ones within that folder, and then move the email into that folder.

Is this possible?

Comment: When you say "any new email like the one ..." what about those emails do you want to match? The sender?

Comment: Sender would work, or subject. I figured Outlook would have some sort of matching algorithm similar to *Right CLick* > Create Rule.

Comment: I don't know of any matching algorithm, but if you know what you are looking for, you can create quite a complex custom rule.

Comment: (and if you *don't* know what you're looking for, how do you expect Outlook to?)